# Wordpress Query 1st Post from Each Taxonomy Category

Tags: wordpress, loops, taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy called "Placements" with categories "government", "politics", "elections" and "democracy"

I would like to use wp_query to pull the first article in each of those categories into my custom loop.

I have the loop code handled, I just can't figure out how to get the query going. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post some code it will be better to get answer

Comment: I am really starting from scratch so I have no idea. If you know how to do this I would really only need to wp_query part. The rest I have figured out. I just can't figure out how to make the filter, without doing four separate loops which is what I am trying to do.